# What "traffic" is Nyles referring to?

Tags: movie, palm-springs

In *Palm Springs (2020)*, because of Nyles, Roy is stuck in a time loop. Nyles asks
Roy to kill him:

> Nyles: Could you kill me one more time? You could still beat the
> **traffic**?
>
> Roy: All right. Side yard.

What "traffic" is Nyles referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in the film is actually slightly different than you've described. It should be

> **Nyles:** *Would you kill me one last time. [slight pause] Y'know, just to [beat the traffic](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/beat-the-traffic#:%7E:text=To%20%22beat%22%20the%20traffic%20means,on%20your%20morning%20commute)?*

In this instance he's referring to the road traffic back to Palm Springs but in actuality he wants Roy to kill him one more time because he feels that it'll bring a sense of closure to the relationship he has with Roy, who's finally managed to deal with his rage issues and doesn't want to see Nyles again.

The [draft script](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Palm-Springs-Screenplay.pdf) offers some commentary on the scene.

> **ROY:** *It’s probably best if we don’t see each other again.*
> (then)
> *It’s not you, it’s me.*
>
> A moment as Nyles absorbs this. Even Roy is done with Nyles.
>
> **NYLES:** *Kill me?*
>
> Roy takes him in -- this defeated shell of a man.
>
> **NYLES:** *The traffic.*
>
> **ROY:** *Side yard.*
> (to Madison)
> *Daddy’ll be right back, honey.*

Comment: And yes, this is a [breakup sex](https://www.verywellmind.com/pros-and-cons-of-breakup-sex-5120159#:~:text=Breakup%20sex%20is%20defined%20as,what%20happens%20past%20that%20point.) joke

Answer (score 2):

Just the traffic he would have to drive thru just to get back to the hotel. So instead he asks jk Simmons character to "kill" him so he would just wake up to restart the loop.

Comment: Wow way better answer

Comment: It's also noteworthy that he doesn't actually need Roy to kill him, Nor does he need to travel back. He could kill himself or take a drug that makes him sleep.